# Is there a way to cache the information from firebase database for fast working?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, caching

I'm using Firebase as my backend, and every time I load an activity, the database reference fetches it. It happens all the time. Is there a way to cache the information of the activity, so that the information loads without the help of firebase reference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store information with SharedPreferences. For example, if I want to save my username, I do this:

To save data:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("myName", "Mauricio");
                editor.apply();
```

To retrieve data:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
String name = preferences.getString("myName", "none"));
```

Note that this "none" is in case to string "myName" be null.